# Styling Components (styled-components) | Superimposing one on top of the other

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The problem is this:

There is a created UiInput React component using styled-components, above it there is also a UiInputExt React component, which should override some of the styles defined in UiInput, but for some reason this does not happen, apparently it does not even add the corresponding class...

I attach the code below:

```
const StyledInput = styled.input`
    color: ${(props) => props.styles.color};

    ::placeholder,
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: ${(props) => props.styles.color};
    }

    :-moz-placeholder {
        color: ${(props) => props.styles.color};
        opacity: 1;
    }

    ::-moz-placeholder {
        color: ${(props) => props.styles.color};
        opacity: 1;
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: ${(props) => props.styles.color};
    }
`;

<StyledInput 
    id={id}
    className={cn(styles.input, classes)}
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    styles={isTheme.styles}
>
</StyledInput>
```

And the corresponding override (which doesn't work!)

```
import UiInput from '../';

const StyledUiInputExt = styled(UiInput)`
    color: ${(props) => props.styles.color_uiinputext};

    ::placeholder,
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: ${(props) => props.styles.color_uiinputext};
    }

    :-moz-placeholder {
        color: ${(props) => props.styles.color_uiinputext};
        opacity: 1;
    }

    ::-moz-placeholder {
        color: ${(props) => props.styles.color_uiinputext};
        opacity: 1;
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: ${(props) => props.styles.color_uiinputext};
    }
`;

<StyledUiInputExt classes={cn(styles.input, classes)} {...props} styles={isTheme.styles}></StyledUiInputExt>
```

Comment: Are you saying that `StyledInput` is imported as `UiInput` in the second snippet? I think you may not be passing the class names correctly. Should it be `<StyledUiInputExt classNames={cn(styles.input, classes)} {...props} styles={isTheme.styles} />`? Perhaps a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live would help us understand the issue more clearly.

Comment: Check if you have access
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-flower-31z2c?file=/src/App.jsx
In my case, the first input should be with blue text, and the second with green, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not exporting the styled component `StyledInput`, rather you are exporting a plain React component that is rendering `StyledInput`.

```
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  color: blue;
`;

const UiInput = () => {
  return <StyledInput />;
};

export default UiInput;
```

UiInputExt

```
import UiInput from "./UiInput";

const StyledInputExt = styled(UiInput)`
  color: green;
`;

const UiInputExt = () => {
  return <StyledInputExt />;
};
```

The style you are applying to `UiInput` isn't applied to the JSX it renders, i.e. it isn't passed through to `StyledInput`.

You can only override other styled-components. For this you should export/import `StyledInput` (*renamed to `UiInput`*) directly.

```
const UiInput = styled.input`
  color: blue;
`;

export default UiInput;
```

[image]

[image: Edit friendly-andras-d7zbv]

An alternative would be to export `UiInput` as a styled component and ensure that the `className` prop is passed through to the `StyledInput` component.

```
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  color: blue;
`;

const UiInput = ({ className }) => {
  return <StyledInput className={className} />;
};

export default styled(UiInput)``;
```

Comment: Please have a look at the current CodeSandbox using your alternative (made some minor edits), how then to override StyledInputExt
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-flower-31z2c?file=/src/UiInput.jsx

Comment: @ИльяПетриков Add `className` as a destructured prop in `UiInput` and pass it through to the `StyledInput`, i.e. `className={\`${className} ${classes}\`}`. https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-wright-r5ln9?file=/src/UiInput.jsx `styled-components` just generates CSS classes and `className` is a string that represents all the classes an element should have.